# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique although the contract exists

Tags: solidity

I have a contract that imports another contract that I have locally:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.4;

import "./ERC1155Tradeable.sol";

contract YieldToken is ERC1155Tradeable { 

...

}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
> Compilation warnings encountered:

    @0xsequence/erc-1155/contracts/utils/Address.sol: Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
,@0xsequence/erc-1155/contracts/utils/ERC165.sol: Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
,@0xsequence/erc-1155/contracts/utils/Ownable.sol: Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
,@0xsequence/erc-1155/contracts/utils/SafeMath.sol: Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
,project:/contracts/ERC1155Tradeable.sol: Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
,project:/contracts/NFT.sol: Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
,project:/contracts/Strings.sol: Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
,project:/contracts/YieldToken.sol: Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
,project:/contracts/NFT.sol: Warning: Source file does not specify required compiler version! Consider adding "pragma solidity ^0.7.4;"

project:/contracts/YieldToken.sol:5:24: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
contract YieldToken is ERC1155Tradeable {
                       ^--------------^

Compilation failed. See above.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

check `./ERC1155Tradeable.sol` contract name. If it is different from file name, you must inherit from contract name.